# Go test failing due to dependency error in specific library

Tags: go

I am trying to run some `go` test which error out as follows:

```
▶ go test -timeout 100000000s -cover -race
# github.com/tj/assert
../../../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/tj/assert@v0.0.1/require.go:191:29: too many arguments in call to assert.HTTPBodyContains
    have (TestingT, http.HandlerFunc, string, string, url.Values, io.Reader, interface {}, []interface {}...)
    want (assert.TestingT, http.HandlerFunc, string, string, url.Values, interface {}, ...interface {})
../../../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/tj/assert@v0.0.1/require.go:203:32: too many arguments in call to assert.HTTPBodyNotContains
    have (TestingT, http.HandlerFunc, string, string, url.Values, io.Reader, interface {}, []interface {}...)
    want (assert.TestingT, http.HandlerFunc, string, string, url.Values, interface {}, ...interface {})
FAIL    github.com/myrepo/myproject/lib/somelib [build failed]
```

In my `go.mod`

```
▶ cat go.mod | grep -i tj
    github.com/tj/assert v0.0.1
```

What is causing the above error?

Answer (score 3):

Line 191 of [`github.com/tj/assert@v0.0.1`](https://github.com/tj/assert/blob/v0.0.1/require.go#L191) is:

```
if !assert.HTTPBodyContains(t, handler, method, url, values, body, str, msgAndArgs...)
```

Due to the import `assert "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"` this is referencing the [stretchr testify package](https://github.com/stretchr/testify/blob/master/assert/http_assertions.go#L114) which defines `HTTPBodyContains` as

```
 HTTPBodyContains(t TestingT, handler http.HandlerFunc, method, url string, values url.Values, str interface{}, msgAndArgs ...interface{})
```

So the cause of the error you are getting seems fairly clear; as the error states:

```
have (TestingT, http.HandlerFunc, string, string, url.Values, io.Reader, interface {}, []interface {}...)
want (assert.TestingT, http.HandlerFunc, string, string, url.Values, interface {}, ...interface {})
```

I suspect that the real issues are:

- You are importing `assert "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"` and calling functions in that package when you intend to run the local version of [HTTPBodyContains](https://github.com/tj/assert/blob/v0.0.3/require.go#L189). To fix that remove the `assert.` from before the function names.
- You are using `assert@v0.0.1` but have later versions. Use `go get` to retrieve the latest release (see the docs on [upgrading dependencies](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules#TOC_4.)).